# 90-2000s movie about escaping from a college

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched the movie around 2010, and maybe some details are not right. The impression is that the plot feels long and there may be several consecutive movies.

The first scene is the hero is wearing headphones to play computer games in his home, and then he was instantly transported to a college, the students of the college are there for similar reasons. The school director told him that his parents had given him permission to be sent to this school. Each student was issued a tablet, but it had limited functionality and seemed to be used to communicate with each other and watch school broadcasts.

After that several students planned to escape from the school, they tried many ways but did not succeed, I remember that at night the campus seems to have infrared ray surveillance. They also discussed in a room at the school, which seemed to be a club room, where it was mentioned that once a student tried to escape via glider, but it did not work.

The school is surrounded by forest, but there are 2 to 3 meters high fences in the forest, and with electricity, the fences are black. One-shot shows the location of the school, which appears to be in the middle of a pristine forest.

Later they seem to have discovered the secret of the school and have found a large computer system in a secret area. This computer system has had many iterations and what they found was an older version. They start this computer, which has artificial intelligence that invites them to play a game and discharges an attack if they don't play or if the game fails. The computer screen is an old-fashioned black and white screen, and the voice is that of a robotic female.

There was also a scene where they were captured on another campus (they were intentionally captured there because they found an exhaust duct in that area that could be used for escape) that seemed to be abandoned and was being used by some experimenters for drug experiments. They even had goblins chasing them as they passed through the exhaust ducts. As a result, the exit end of the pipe seems to be locked.

I don't remember how, but a student eventually walked out of the school walls and a virtual projection of a woman congratulated him on his success and said he was the next generation of artificial intelligence for the previously mentioned computer system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be remembering the TV series ["Tower Prep"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1480669/).

[Trailer for the show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52TBMlrB4Yg)

Details which fit:

- The show aired in 2010
- The protagonist is shown playing video games in the first episode, blacks out, and wakes up at the school (see the [summary of the first episode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Prep#Episodes) )
- The school is under surveillance and the students try more than once to escape
- The school is surrounded by a forest
- The school is controlled by a computer system (Whisper) who can project an image of herself as a woman (and does so in the final episode of the first (only) season)
- "They even had goblins chasing them as they passed through the exhaust ducts" - they call them "gnomes" in the series. IIRC, they're never clearly shown, but might be either monsters or robots.

Comment: Huh. I don't know why it's no longer present, but I posted a link to a wiki which has some images of the [Gnomes](https://towerprep.fandom.com/wiki/Gnome). More can be found in official clips on YouTube. Apparently, it's other students under the suits of the Gnomes, possibly under mind control.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

***[The Mangler 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0260162/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2002)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mangler_2):

> *The Mangler 2* (also known as *The Mangler 2: Graduation Day*) is a 2002 Canadian horror film and a direct-to-video sequel to the 1995 theatrical release *The Mangler*, which was based on a 1972 short story of the same name by Stephen King. It stars Lance Henriksen and Chelse Swain. While the original was about a demon-possessed industrial laundry-machine, this film places the demon in a private school's computer network, where it manifests as a destructive computer virus with some of the same abilities as a ouija board.

Comment: Sadly not this one, but thank you